# Error while deploying Rails application to EC2 using Rubber gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, amazon-ec2

I am trying to deploy a rails3.1 app to EC2 using rubber 1.15.0 gem. I followed the instructions in the quick start guide here: https://github.com/wr0ngway/rubber/wiki/Quick-Start. i also setup private and public keys correctly as mentioned in faq. However, Almost towards the end of >cap rubber:generate_staging command I get this error:

```
[production.foo.com] /bin/bash -l -c 'sudo -p '\''sudo password: '\''  bash -l -c '\''cd /mnt/app-production/releases/20120314070940 && RUBBER_ENV=production RAILS_ENV=production ./script/rubber config '\'''
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] bash: ./script/rubber: No such file or directory
    command finished in 418ms
failed: "/bin/bash -l -c 'sudo -p '\\''sudo password: '\\''  bash -l -c '\\''cd /mnt/app-production/releases/20120314070940 && RUBBER_ENV=production RAILS_ENV=production ./script/rubber config '\\'''" on production.foo.com
```

I looked at script folder and found no rubber file. It seems that that ruber script file is not generated after vulcanize command. Does anyone know what command do I need to generate that rubber script file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked this question on google groups and received this answer:

> > > >
> > >       The rubber script was added in the 2.0 prereleases.  It looks like you
> > >       may have the wrong version installed someplace.  Can you please verify
> > >       you're using 1.15.0 both locally and remote?

Infact, this is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with the remote version using the wrong version of rubber.  Perhaps your local copy and deployed copy are different, due to pulling from a branch or other source?  See here: https://groups.google.com/group/rubber-ec2/browse_thread/thread/ff0c8907b4d5aa7f

Comment: i asked this question in that gogoel group and got answer there. Thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score -1):

There is no need for a rubber script on the local machine the script is ran on the ec2 instance. all you need are the configuration files in config/rubber.